# Dynamically changing log level without restarting the application

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Is it possible to change the log level using `fileConfig` without restarting the application? If it cannot be achieved through `fileConfig`, is there some other way to get the same result?

This is for an application running on a server, I want sys admins to be able to change a config file that is picked during run time by the application and change the log level dynamically.

Comment: Everyone using threads and timers to reset the logging level.  This is what signals were invented for.  You can signal a process using "SIGHUP" (which is the standard on *nix) to reload configuration.  In python you can install a signal handler that will catch this (event drive) and thus reload or reset a configuration.

Comment: I agree about using signals.  Suggest using SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 for this purpose instead of SIGHUP. The latter is sent when a process's controlling terminal disconnects.

Comment: `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` are only available for Unix-like system. You could use `logging.config.listen()` to listen for new configurations (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.listen)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

`fileConfig` is a mechanism to configure the log level for you based on a file; you can dynamically change it at any time in your program.

Call [`.setLevel()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) on the logging object for which you want to change the log level. Usually you'd do that on the root:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Also see the answer by @sfinkens (and my comment there) in case you only want to change the setLevel for a particular handler.

Comment: Does this mean, if I change loglevel in the file whilst the program is already running, the change will take effect? Does it use inotify to watch the conf file for changes?

Comment: @0xc0de: no, the file is not being re-parsed. You can change the log level *of the `Logger` objects* that are currently used in a running Python program.

Answer (score 59):

In addition to the accepted answer: Depending on how you initialized the logger, you might also have to update the logger's handlers:

```
import logging

level = logging.DEBUG
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(level)
for handler in logger.handlers:
    handler.setLevel(level)
```

Comment: Useful:  If you used a dictConfig to specify your Loggers, Handlers, etc, and you only want to setLevel on one particular Handler, you can use the .get_name() function in such a loop as is shown by @sfinkens here, and make sure you only change the level of the one you want.

Comment: Why would handlers need to have a logLevel? Moreover, why can their level be set independently from the logger that owns them?
This is terribly confusing, and bad design.

Comment: @CodeKid what if you want to log to file at a DEBUG level, but to the console at a different level? Would you not attach two handlers with different levels?

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on [sfinken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46710435/11678073), and Starman's subsequent comment, you can also check the type of the handler to target a specific outputter - for instance:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
for handler in logger.handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, type(logging.StreamHandler())):
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.debug('Debug logging enabled')
```

Comment: just what I needed to automatically enable debug logging if I'm running without the -o flag

Comment: Thanks for this! A small suggestion tho: `isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler)`

Answer (score 10):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Note that `getLogger()` called without any arguments returns the root logger.

Comment: This is the same as Martjin's answer, which doesn't seem to affect existing loggers (at least in Python2.7). sfinken's answer does affect existing loggers.

Answer (score 10):

It is certainly possible to use `fileConfig()` to change logging configuration on the fly, though for simple changes a programmatic approach as suggested in Martijn Pieters' answer might be appropriate. Logging even provides a socket server to listen for config changes using the `listen()` / `stopListening()` APIs, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#configuration-server-example). To get logging to listen on a particular port, you use

```
t = logging.config.listen(PORT_NUMBER)
t.start()
```

and to stop listening, call

```
logging.config.stopListening()
```

To send data to the server, you can use e.g.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', PORT_NUMBER))
with open(CONFIG_FILE) as f:
    data_to_send = f.read()
s.send(struct.pack('>L', len(data_to_send)))
s.send(data_to_send)
s.close()
```

**Update:** Due to backwards-compatibility constraints, the internal implementation of the `fileConfig()` call means that you can't specify `disable_existing_loggers=False` in the  call, which makes this feature less useful in certain scenarios. You can use the same API to send a JSON file using the dictConfig schema, which will allow better control over the reconfiguration. This requires Python 2.7/3.2 or above (where `dictConfig()` was added). Or, you can use the stdlib code to implement your own listener which works in the same way but which is tailored to your specific needs.

Comment: Wow I saw this answer earlier today, but didn't notice the update. I struggled with exactly that issue. There is a bug filed to add the option.

http://bugs.python.org/issue26533

Now I got around the issue in an underhanded way:

Comment: ```python
def my_fileConfig(fname, defaults=None, disable_existing_loggers=False):
    """
    This does _NOTHING_ but call fileConfig with disable_existing_loggers set
    to False instead of true. It is intended to monkey patcn it out, so that the
    config listener can be used without disabling all non-root loggers.
    """
    orig_fileConfig(fname, defaults, disable_existing_loggers)

orig_fileConfig = logging.config.fileConfig
# HACK: Patch out fileConfig for my version.
logging.config.fileConfig = my_fileConfig
logging.config.fileConfig(config_path)
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally settled with using inotify and gevent to check for the file write operation, and once I know the file has been changed then I go and set the level for each logger I have based on the config.

```
import gevent
import gevent_inotifyx as inotify
from gevent.queue import Queue

class FileChangeEventProducer(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, fd, queue):
        gevent.Greenlet.__init__(self)
        self.fd = fd
        self.queue = queue

    def _run(self):
        while True:
            events = inotify.get_events(self.fd)
            for event in events:
                self.queue.put(event)
                gevent.sleep(0)


class FileChangeEventConsumer(gevent.Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, queue, callBack):
        gevent.Greenlet.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.callback = callBack

    def _run(self):
        while True:
            _ = self.queue.get()
            self.callback()
            gevent.sleep(0)


class GeventManagedFileChangeNotifier:
    def __init__(self, fileLocation, callBack):
        self.fileLocation = fileLocation
        self.callBack = callBack
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.fd = inotify.init()
        self.wd = inotify.add_watch(self.fd, self.fileLocation, inotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)


    def start(self):
        producer = FileChangeEventProducer(self.fd, self.queue)
        producer.start()
        consumer = FileChangeEventConsumer(self.queue, self.callBack)
        consumer.start()
        return (producer, consumer)
```

The above code gets used like below,

```
    def _setUpLoggingConfigFileChangeNotifier(self):
        loggingFileNameWithFullPath = self._getFullPathForLoggingConfig()
        self.gFsNotifier = GeventManagedFileChangeNotifier(loggingFileNameWithFullPath, self._onLogConfigChanged)
        self.fsEventProducer, self.fsEventConsumer = self.gFsNotifier.start()


    def _onLogConfigChanged(self):
        self.rootLogger.info('Log file config has changed - examining the changes')
        newLoggingConfig = Config(self.resourcesDirectory, [self.loggingConfigFileName]).config.get('LOG')
        self.logHandler.onLoggingConfigChanged(newLoggingConfig)
```

Once I have the new log file config I can wire in the right logging level for each logger from config. I just wanted to share the answer and it might help someone if they are trying to use it with gevent.

Answer (score 2):

Use `logging.basicConfig` with `force=True`.

Example:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger.info('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
print()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING, force=True)

logger.info('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
exit()
```

And the output:

```
INFO:root:debug
INFO:root:info
WARNING:root:warning

WARNING:root:warning
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer for newer Python (>=3.8). For anyone else, the documentation for this is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app, you first need to find a way for reloading that file or resetting the log level based on your own config file during execution.

Easiest way would be to use a timer. Either use threading to do that, or make your async framework to do that (if you use any; they usually implement it).

Using threading.Timer:

```
import threading
import time


def reset_level():
    # you can reload your own config file or use logging.config.fileConfig here
    print 'Something else'
    pass


t = threading.Timer(10, reset_level)
t.start()

while True:
    # your app code
    print 'Test'
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output:

```
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Something else
Test
Test
```

Update: 
Please check the solution proposed by Martijn Pieters.

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question.

Comment: I've used the above solution and the problem i'm facing (on rhel5 with python 2.4.3 and using ConcurrentLogHandler) is that for every reload of the config file, it add's a file handle and after running for a while it throws a "Too many open files" exception. So i agree with Travis Bear that the anwser from Martijn Pieters should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Fabian76 did you close that file anyway? Use context manager to open a file rather than using the standalone `open` method.