# Change logging level dynamically in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am logging messages from various modules and want to change the log level dynamically.  The code snippet is

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.WARNING, force=True)

# Code here that works so only worry about WARNINGs
# ....

# Code here has an issue so increase log level to DEBUG

logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This gives the error `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'setLevel'`.  I tried using the logger generated by `basicConfig`, e.g.

```
L = logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO, force=True)
L.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

but got the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'logging'`. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617355/dynamically-changing-log-level-without-restarting-the-application

Comment: Do you mean that you get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setLevel'` in the last example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically changing log level without restarting the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617355/dynamically-changing-log-level-without-restarting-the-application)

Comment: Hi both - thanks for the link to the solution.  I changed my code to     logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG) and it works as expected