# Temporarily change logging level - safely

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, python-logging

According to [Dynamically changing log level without restarting the application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617355/850781) I can temporarily change logging level:

```
logger_level = my_logger.level
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
a = do_something_with_higher_logging1()
b,c = do_something_with_higher_logging2()
d = do_something_with_higher_logging3()
my_logger.setLevel(logger_level)
```

The problem is that if `do_something_with_higher_logging[123]` raise an exception (which is caught outside this, so my program is not terminated), the level of `my_logger` is not reset back and stays at `DEBUG`.

I can do

```
def call_with_loglevel(logger, level, f, **kwargs):
    "Call f with logger at a different level"
    saved_logger_level = logger.level
    logger.setLevel(level)
    try:
        return f(**kwargs)
    finally:
        logger.setLevel(saved_logger_level)
```

but this requires me to define `f` out of the `do_something_with_higher_logging[123]`...

What I want is something like

```
with my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG):
    a = do_something_with_higher_logging1()
    b,c = do_something_with_higher_logging2()
    d = do_something_with_higher_logging3()
```

Answer (score 1):

Making [`Logger.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) return a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) seems like a backwards-compatible change (should I create an RFE?) but for now it looks like I can do

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def log_level(logger, level):
    "Run body with logger at a different level"
    saved_logger_level = logger.level
    logger.setLevel(level)
    try:
        yield saved_logger_level
    finally:
        logger.setLevel(saved_logger_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a recipe for this in the [Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging):

> There are times when it would be useful to temporarily change the logging configuration and revert it back after doing something. For this, a context manager is the most obvious way of saving and restoring the logging context. Here is a simple example of such a context manager, which allows you to optionally change the logging level and add a logging handler purely in the scope of the context manager:

```
import logging
import sys

class LoggingContext:
    def __init__(self, logger, level=None, handler=None, close=True):
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = level
        self.handler = handler
        self.close = close

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.level is not None:
            self.old_level = self.logger.level
            self.logger.setLevel(self.level)
        if self.handler:
            self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)

    def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
        if self.level is not None:
            self.logger.setLevel(self.old_level)
        if self.handler:
            self.logger.removeHandler(self.handler)
        if self.handler and self.close:
            self.handler.close()
        # implicit return of None => don't swallow exceptions
```